# How to access a default class property from an object?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have the following challenge, that I did not succeed. And I could not find an example of someone who bumped on the same problem.

```
class MyClass {
    name = 'default name'
}

let instance = new MyClass();
instance.name = 'new name';

# At this point I want to be able to access the default 'name' of my class (value: 'default name')
```

I am curious about how to approach this the best.

Answer (score 2):

Given the code in the question *exactly*, it's not possible unless you create a new instance. With

```
name = 'default name'
```

you assign to the `name` property of the instance object. Then with

```
instance.name = 'new name';
```

you overwrite the `name` property of the instance object. The `'default name'` no longer exists anywhere in the prototype chain.

So, create a new instance to run the class field again:

```js
class MyClass {
    name = 'default name'
}

let instance = new MyClass();
instance.name = 'new name';

const newInstance = new MyClass();
console.log(newInstance.name);
```

A better pattern would be to put the default value on the *prototype*. That way, you can examine the property on the prototype *or* the property on the instance:

```js
class MyClass {
    
}
MyClass.prototype.name = 'default name';

let instance = new MyClass();
instance.name = 'new name';

console.log(instance.name);
console.log(MyClass.prototype.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by the other answers, there is no straight-forward way, you have to create a new instance.

However, if you need this more often, you could create the instance once and reuse it:

```js
class MyClass {
  name = 'default name'
}

MyClass.prototype.defaults = Object.freeze(new MyClass())

// ------------

let instance = new MyClass()
instance.name = 'new name'
console.log(instance.name) // new name
console.log(instance.defaults.name) // default name
```

I'm additionally using `Object.freeze` to prevent accidental modifications to the default instance.

You could also assign to `MyClass.defaults`, but then you'd have to use `instance.constructor.defaults.name` or `MyClass.defaults.name`.

Comment: I think this is very useful for my application. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new temporary instance and get the name

```js
class MyClass {
    name = 'default name'
}

let instance = new MyClass();
instance.name = 'new name';

console.log((new MyClass()).name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Is there a way to access the Class through the Instance? I want to write a generic method in the parent class that can reset a property to its initial value. I don't see how I can do it through this approach. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: `instance.constructor` will be `MyClass`